# Why does Android have a call log limit for the call history?

Tags: call-history

I just noticed recently that Android limits the call log to 500 entries.
This means many people will quickly lose their call history.
I would like to know for what reason one would limit the call history.

Comment: Technical limitations perhaps?  Otherwise, it might be an arbitrary number.  I, for one, am not going through 500 calls to see who called.

Comment: Technical limitations are hard to imagine and the idea of a call log is to find a number or date of a call some time ago. With 10 calls per day you cannot even go back more than 2 month which limits its use.

Comment: I'm afraid all we can do is guess here (unless those folks who set the limit chime in). As for having lost history: well, there's always backups … and like SiX wrote, I suspect most people won't hit the limit (or rather won't note it). I cannot remember having had the need to check whom I called 3 month ago ;)